# It says that ‘Adam was created alone to teach you...’ alone as opposed to what?

Tags: maseches-sanhedrin, adam

Adam was created alone to teach you that whoever takes a human life is considered to have destroyed an entire world. And whoever saves a human life is considered as if he preserved an entire world (Sanhedrin 4.5).

How else could Adam have been created other than alone? What’s the alternative?

Comment: @DanF Perhaps. But the simple reading of the Passuk is that it's talking about a mate: https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.2.18?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en 'The LORD God said, “It is not good for man to be alone; I will make a fitting helper for him.” '

Answer (score 2):

Sanhedrin 37a explains (excerpt from Sefaria):

> Therefore, Adam the first man was created alone, to teach you that
>   with regard to anyone who destroys one soul from the Jewish people,
>   i.e., kills one Jew, the verse ascribes him blame as if he destroyed
>   an entire world, as Adam was one person, from whom the population of
>   an entire world came forth.

Or, another perspective - all the other creatures were created as species or groups. E.g. numerous birds, fowl, fish, etc. were created simultaneously. But just one man was created.

Comment: Follow-up question - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/105732/5275